# Check if two voltages (with different grounds) are within 0.5 V of each other

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator, voltage-measurement

I have designed the following circuit that should be able to detect if two voltages *Bus Bar VBAT* and *VBAT* that are referenced to *Bus Bar GND* and *GND*, respectively, are within 0.5 V of each other.

On the left side I have used two Differential Amplifiers circuits with gain 1 to measure each of the voltages, given that *Bus Bar VBAT* and *VBAT* can range between 42 and 58.8 V, I added the voltage divider to attenuate the signal.

This part of the circuit is working as expected but the part in the middle, the comparators, are having a very strange behaviour.

- If *Bus Bar VBAT* = *VBAT* = 0 V -> Both comparators output 3.3 V, as expected;
- If *Bus Bar VBAT* is lower than *VBAT* or higher only one of the comparators outputs 3.3 V as expected;
- But if *Bus Bar VBAT* = *VBAT* = some voltage, for example 52.8 V the output of each comparator is around 1.7 V, when it should be 3.3 V.

I have used LTSpice to simulate this circuit and it worked perfectly, I don't understand what's the problem here.

Before someone notices it, I forgot to add the pull-up resistors on the output of the LMV393S-13 but I have already done so on my board.

**EDIT:** Maybe it shouldn’t have been done like this, like @jsotola said both grounds are connected, but there is a resistance of more than 1 MOhm between both grounds. This circuit is used to check if the battery voltage is within 0.5 V of other battery voltage so that the BMS can decide if it is safe to make an put both batteries in parallel. The problem here is that the BMS cuts the battery with a low side switch, which means that I can’t simply connect both grounds and measure the difference between both voltages. Otherwise, I would be bypassing the BMS and connecting the batteries in parallel without checking if it is safe.

[image: Circuit]

Comment: `with different grounds` ... how are the two grounds isolated? ... your schematic diagram shows the two grounds connected

Comment: Maybe it shouldn’t have been done like this. But there is a resistance of more than 1 MOhm between both grounds.

Comment: How have you measured the outputs of the comparators - multimeter or oscilloscope? Are you sure they're not oscillating?

Comment: I would measure both voltages digitally, and then pass the result through an optocoupler. Passing an analog signal between 2 grounds is very tricky, and subject to all sorts of noise issues.

Comment: Do you mean the high sides of the batteries are always connected? That's the opposite of isolated and  makes it much easier.

Comment: @brhans that’s a good point I don’t have an oscilloscope yet so it was measured with a multimeter, but it seems to be very stable. Nonetheless, you are right I should check with an oscilloscope.

Comment: @Drew how would you measure them digitally? ADCs are quite expensive compared to OPAMPs that’s why I went this way.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany can you elaborate? The positive of the battery is always ON and the BMS only cuts the GND, but if the GNDs are not connected together you have two different references right?

Comment: If the positives are always connected together then you can look at the (-) of the disconnected battery with a high impedance measurement and if it's outside +/-0.5V from (the other) GND you're okay.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I suppose you are talking about using an OPAMP as a differential amplifier, but if the difference is bigger than 3.3V (the only voltage I have besides the battery voltage) the OPAMP will saturate, or not?

Comment: The circuitry is a detail. You can divide and offset it so that a 3.3V rail is okay.

Comment: @Sebastião Many low end MCUs have a built in ADC. 2 of those, plus an optoisolator so they can communicate, and you're good. The analog measurement is much simpler if you don't need to worry about differential signals, common mode noise, etc.